# Reupdate Set Orders with Custom Comparator

Tags: c++, stl, set, comparator

I'm solving a CP-like problem, that's why this question seems a little bit nonsense.

Let's say I have struct `Item`, and I'm storing them inside an `unorderd_map`. Then I keep the pointer of the map elements inside a `Set` that is sorted by the speed of `Item`.

My goal is to find out which Item has the fastest speed quickly. Here's the code:

```
struct Item{
    int speed;
    int id;
};

struct cmp{
    bool operator()(Item *I1, Item *I2) const{
        if(I1->speed == I2->speed) return I1->id < I2->id;
        return I1->speed > I2->speed;
    }
};

unordered_map<int, Item> MP;
set<Item*, cmp> S;

int main(){
    MP[2] = Item(2, 20);
    MP[1] = Item(1, 10);
    MP[3] = Item(3, 30);
    
    for(auto it = MP.begin(); it != MP.end(); ++it){
        S.insert(&it->second);
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried to update the speed of an `Item`, but the order of the `set` remains the same.

With my solution, is there any way to reorder the Set when I update one of the element's speeds without clearing the Set?

I'm looking for a better solution too, thank you. :)

Comment: delete and reinsert the element you updated?

Comment: I would delete, then update, and finally reinsert. This to ensure the internal algorithms of set will not go haywire when the strict ordering is violated.

Comment: I assume you have a specific reason why you are not using `std::map` or `std::multimap`? Slightly unrelated: You can use `std::tie(I1->speed, I1->id) < std::tie(I2->speed, I2->id)` in your comparator as a simplification. `std::tie` creates a tuple of references and tuples are always compared lexicographically.

Comment: @Botje If I'm doing that, I have to iterate through the set to find the updated element. But I think this is the fastest way, thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, unordered_map has faster random access, and I don't need the map to be sorted. anyway, thanks for the information
@joergbrech

Comment: I seem to be missing the point, because to me it seemed like the whole idea of using `set` is because you kinda do want the items to be sorted. I wouldn't expect a huge performance drop, unless random access is right in your critical path and you have very  tight performance requirements. But even then, I would start with the idiomatic solution, benchmark and go from there. Otherwise you will never know if the added complexity is justified.